# enabling UIBarButtonItem when textfield has input

Tags: iphone, uitextfield, uibarbuttonitem

I am trying to disable my send button (UIBarButtonItem within a toolbar) whenever there is no input in the "userInput" UITextField, and enable it when there is. Here is the code I've written - I can't quite figure out why it isnt working.

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {

if (userInput.text.length >0) {
    [sendButton setEnabled:YES];
}else{
    [sendButton setEnabled:NO];
}
```

}

Im also getting a warning that says "control reaches end of non-void function."

Im very new to xcode and programming so I'm not sure what that is telling me.

Thanks for any help!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The text field object sends the message `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` to its delegate asking whether the change (adding the new character or removing a character) should be permitted or not. Since you don't want to refuse any changes made to the text field itself, you must return `YES` from this method. The warning

```
control reaches end of non-void function
```

means you have a non-void function so you are supposed to return something. Since nothing was being returned, this message popped up.

One important thing to remember is that this delegate method is called **before** the change is made, which makes sense because the delegate is being asked for permission to allow or disallow the change. If the delegate refuses, the text field's value will remain the same regardless of what the user types.

So calling `userInput.text` is useless because it will give the old value back as the change hasn't been made yet. However, there is enough information in the parameters of this method to construct the new *to-be* value of the text field.

```
NSString *newText = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string]);
```

The complete method would look like,

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    NSString *newText = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string]; 
    BOOL isFieldEmpty = [newText isEqualToString:@""];
    sendButton.enabled = !isFieldEmpty;
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: - (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    NSString *newText = [userInput.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string]; 
 
 if ([newText isEqualToString:@""]){
  sendButton.enabled = NO;
 }else {
  sendButton.enabled = YES;
 }
 
 return YES;
}

Comment: @jeff - Is your method getting called at all? try setting a breakpoint, or logging something. Did you set the delegate for the text field, something similar to `userInput.delegate = self;`. If that doesn't help, then add more code - specifically the parts where the text field is being created, and its delegate is being set.

Comment: im not sure the method is getting called. I wrote in simply

Comment: [sendButton setEnabled:NO];
return YES;

Comment: and the button remained enabled.

Comment: ok, so seems the method is not getting called. most likely you didn't set the text field delegate, or set it on a wrong object. show some more code.

Comment: I'm not sure how to set a delegate, but I'm consulting the documentation and im thinking maybe i should write this for the property: @property(nonatomic, assign) id<UITextFieldDelegate> delegate

Comment: Got it!! thanks for all your help guys realllly appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

ok you need in set enable NO in vieWillAppear

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
  [self.sendButton setEnabled:NO];

}

-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {

if (userInput.text.length >0) {
    [self.sendButton setEnabled:YES];
}else{
    [self.sendButton setEnabled:NO];
    }
   return YES;
}
```

make UIBarButton as property and IBOUtlet and make proper connection

.h

```
UIBarButton *sendButton;

@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIBarButton *sendButton;
```

and in .m

```
@synthesize sendButton;
```

and

```
-(void)dealloc
{
  [self.sendButton release];
  [super dealloc];
}
```

and also remember to make connection for `textField` from IB.

Comment: I've done all thsi and adjusted my code but I still can't get it to work :(

Comment: check you textField delegate connection and tab Bar button connection.

Answer (score 0):

```
 -(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {

    if (userInput.text.length >0) {
        [sendButton setEnabled:YES];
    }else{
        [sendButton setEnabled:NO];
    }
    return YES;
    }
```

Comment: no winner. It can;t be this hard I must be doing something wrong somewhere  . . . .

Answer (score 0):

In your controller add (weak) outlets for both the `UITextView` and `UIBarButtonItem` and hook them up to the items in view.

Add another `IBAction` to controller for example:

```
- (void)textChanged:(id)sender
{
     if ( [self.someTextField.text length] > 0 )
         [self.someBarButtonItem setEnabled:YES];
     else [self.someBarButtonItem setEnabled:NO];
}
```

Hook up `UITextView`'s `Edit Changed` event to the `textChanged:` you've just created.
The `Edit Changed` even fires up when characters are typed into `UITextField`, you check the length of the text and enable/disable `UIBarButtonItem` when the text field has some text.

You can also in `viewDidLoad:` check the initial text length and enable/disable the button depending on the text.

Hope that helps.
It works for me in iOS 6.1.